# Setting $_POST variables as a means of passing data / Not passing parameters in functions

Tags: php, coding-standards, functions

I've got a legacy PHP web application wherein almost each and every function makes references to $_POST variables - retrieving their values, AND **setting them (or setting new POST variables)** as a means to communicate with the calling code or other functions.

eg:

```
function addevent()
{
...
$add_minutes=$_POST['minutes'];     
...
$_POST['event_price']=''; 
...
}
```

I would have thought that the straightforward approach would have been to pass to a function all the values that it needs, and return all what they generate.

As an old-school programmer, albeit a bit out of touch now, I find this structure grotesquely unsettling - where data is passed arbitrarily all over the place. What do others think? Is the above approach acceptable now?

---

Edit 1

One conceivably genuine use-case is as follows. This is a function which handles embed tags or an uploaded file.

```
function brandEvent($edit_id='')
{
...
    switch($_POST['upload_or_embed'])
    {
        case 'embed':
        ...
        // uses $_POST['embed_video_code']
        ...
        break;
        case 'upload':
        ...
        // uses DIFFERENT POST variables
        ...
    }
}
```

Is this a sensible code structure?

Comment: codereview.se seems more appropriate for this question.

Comment: @Chris: I disagree, because he's not trying to get his own code fixed up.

Comment: @DeadMG: Perhaps this does fall under "Development Methodologies" or "Design Patterns" from Faq.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As an old-school programmer, albeit a bit out of touch now, I find
>   this structure grotesquely unsettling - where data is passed
>   arbitrarily all over the place. What do others think?

I, too, find this structure grotesquely unsettling. Those functions should be atomic, independent of external influences. Your examples can be called *programming by coincidence* and this is a horrible practice. It's unrobust code depending on side-effects and globals and will likely cause headaches for maintenance programmers. This style also effectively limits the reusability and testability of those functions, as they are so tightly coupled to a specific POST of variables (probably from the view).

This approach is by no means acceptable.

Comment: Thanks  - any thoughts on reasons besides maintainability? Could you point out some programming standards / approaches it violates? @DeadMG ?

Comment: I pretty much pointed out all there is to say. This style is unacceptable for the reasons I mentioned. And those are some very good reasons. I know it's hard to communicate them to inexperienced developers. Bad reusability, testability, maintainability, dependence on globals...that's probably the worst you can say about code at all.

Comment: @matt74tm: Just imagine you wanted stateful URLs with this code ...

Answer (score 1):

> As an old-school programmer, albeit a bit out of touch now, I find
>   this structure grotesquely unsettling - where data is passed
>   arbitrarily all over the place. What do others think? Is the above
>   approach acceptable now?

No, the above approach is completely not acceptable now. If anything, it used to be a lot more acceptable than it is now. Such code is virtually impossible to reason about and would be an incredibly unmaintainable mess. You're absolutely right to label it as hideous.